# Binaries and libraries configuration for installed application (UBUNTU 16.04 LTS)

Tags: linux, software-installation, version

I am facing an issue repeatedly. For example, say I install Python2.4 and then I install python 3.0, both files are retained in system I see in /usr/bin and /usr/local/lib or /usr/lib.

How do I configure in such case that my running programs based on the software (python in this example) to pick particular version out of multiple versions.

I believe the soft links exists which point to either of the version's files, but how do I configure that soft link to point to corresponding version files as required by me...

Answer (score 0):

Debian-based systems (such as Ubuntu) use the [Debian Alternatives System](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) to determine which applications are linked in `/usr/bin` and other shared system directories.

You can see what files are linked in the `/etc/alternatives` directory.

To update these links, use the `update-alternatives --config` command with the name of the application you would like to change (requires root or `sudo`).

**Example:**

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config view

There are 2 choices for the alternative view (providing /usr/bin/view).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```